# How to pass a parameter using trigger in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a method that trigger a custom event.

```
   keyDown: function(keycode) {
        $(window.APP).trigger('keyDown', keycode);
    },
```

I need to catch `keycode` from window.APP.
At the moment even passing a proper value for keyDown when result for alert is always undefined.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

---

in window.APP

```
keyDown: function(keyCode) {
     alert(keyCode);
    }
}
```

I am using jQuery 1.4.2

Comment: side note: if you are going to support different browsers, you have to know that the keydown event is "evil", cause different browsers use different codes. I suggest you to check this link http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html, for understanding the problems you'll face and this link to perform a fast test (without wondering in the developer tools) http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
keyDown: function(event, keyCode) {
     alert(keyCode);
    }
```

Comment: @GibboK check this small sample http://tinker.io/73f85, it is working as expected

Answer (score 1):

According to the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), the second parameter for `trigger` is an array, so you probably should call it as `$(window.APP).trigger('keydown', [keyCode])`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
keyDown: function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    $(window.APP).trigger('keyDown', code);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Custom event**

```
keyDown: function(e) {
    $(window.APP).trigger('keyDown', e);
},
```

in **window.APP**

```
keyDown: function(e) {
     k=e.keyCode || e.which;
     alert(k);
}
```